# Updating object ID with identity after saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, updates

I am trying to figure out the best way to update the ID of an existing object after it is saved to the database.

E.g. In the example below, `ContactDetailID` in the `test` method below is always 0 until I physically get it again, I would like to update this automatically as soon as the item is saved.

Stepping through the code below `ContactDetailID` is set once `context.SaveChanges` is called and the item is saved to the database correctly, so I just need to push the ID back up to the UI.

What is the best way to do this?

```
    private void Test()
    {
        int id = 0

        ContactDetail cd = new ContactDetail();
        cd.ContactTypeID = 1;
        cd.Value = "3";
        cd.Save();

        id = cd.ContactDetailID;    
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        ContactDetailDAO service = new ContactDetailDAO();
        ContactDetailDTO saveItem = new ContactDetailDTO();

        if (IsValid(this))
        {
            saveItem.ContactDetailID = this.ContactDetailID;
            saveItem.Value = this.Value;
            saveItem.ContactTypeID = this.ContactTypeID;

            service.Save(saveItem);

            this.ContactDetailID = saveItem.ContactDetailID;
        }
    }

    public void Save(ContactDetailDTO ContactDetailDTO)
    {
        if (ContactDetailDTO.IsNew())
        {
            repository.Add(new tblContactDetail
            {
                ContactDetailID = ContactDetailDTO.ContactDetailID,
                Value = ContactDetailDTO.Value,
                ContactTypeID = ContactDetailDTO.ContactTypeID
            });
        }
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add a null entity.");
        }

        this.context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by changing Add to be a public virtual Int and then bubbling that all the way back up to the Save method. Then I changed the save method to physically set the ID after the save had occurred - service.Save(saveItem, out objectID); this.ContactDetailID = objectID;. So your answer would have helped, marked as useful.

Comment: I'm happy that was useful!

Answer (score 1):

Or use something like this:

```
private void Test()
{
    ContactDetail cd = new ContactDetail();
    cd.ContactTypeID = 1;
    cd.Value = "3";
    cd.Save();
    return cd.ContactDetailID;    
}

public ContactDetailDTO Save()
{
    ContactDetailDAO service = new ContactDetailDAO();
    ContactDetailDTO saveItem = new ContactDetailDTO();

    if (IsValid(this))
    {
        saveItem.ContactDetailID = this.ContactDetailID;
        saveItem.Value = this.Value;
        saveItem.ContactTypeID = this.ContactTypeID;

        saveItem=service.Save(saveItem);

        this.ContactDetailID = saveItem.ContactDetailID;
    }
    return saveItem; 
}

public ContactDetailDTO Save(ContactDetailDTO ContactDetailDTO)
{
    if (ContactDetailDTO.IsNew())
    {
        return repository.Add(new tblContactDetail
        {
            ContactDetailID = ContactDetailDTO.ContactDetailID,
            Value = ContactDetailDTO.Value,
            ContactTypeID = ContactDetailDTO.ContactTypeID
        });
    }
}

public virtual T Add(T entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;

    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add a null entity.");
    }

    this.context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    this.context.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ID column be auto increment it automatically will be updated after `SaveChanges` and then you can easily put a `return` value to UI as something like this:

```
private void Test()
{
    ContactTypeID = 1;
    Value = "3";
    Save();
    return ContactDetailID;    
}
```

and why you create new `ContactDetail();` while you are assign

```
this.ContactDetailID = saveItem.ContactDetailID;
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response. In your example above cd.ContactDetailID is still 0, it remains as 0 until I call a get method to re-retrieve the object.